# Mysqld.exe RAM size increasing upto 130MB and performance is poor

Tags: mysql, memory, java, database-performance, ramdisk

I have deployed my application with java 8 and mysql server. While running mysqld.exe takes upto 130 MB of RAM size and it stops increasing. But after that my application's performance is very poor. Can anyone help me in Identifying the reason behind this. Which factor increases the RAM size of mysqld.exe and why my application getting stucked with database. Thanks in Advance

Comment: 130MB is pretty tiny for a database. You would need to provide MUCH more information to get any useful help - you haven't said what your problem is, what your environment is, what the software is, etc.

Comment: My problem here is My application is stucked with respect to database even if it is handled by threads. Is it because of the load?

Comment: You're going to need to do diagnostics yourself. We can't solve this problem for you, especially with the dearth of information provided. Looking at error logs for database and application would be a good first step.

Answer (score 1):

Relational database servers will (in every case I've worked with) consume all available RAM in the system to cache and optimize search algorithms.  You can specify upper limits on how much it is allowed to consume... but for the most part the defaults are usually pretty good for a simple database environment.

In today's servers... if you're complaining about 130mb of RAM... you should not be using mysql... or ANY relational database server.  I've built database servers designed to operate "normally" consuming well over 100GB of RAM.  If you're working with a relatively small database... and extremely limited resources... try looking at sqlite3 or something that is file-based without a dedicated process that is designed to efficiently keep track of what relates to what.  Extremely limited system resources also means that your "performance" is not ever going to be "great."

Comment: 130mb of RAM is not my problem. The problem is my application getting stucked once mysqld.exe reached 130mb. I dont know why this happens. All my connections are taken over by multiple threads. Still the problem persists.

Comment: How much RAM is available in the system? Is swap being used?  Did you build your indexes correctly?  Are you doing Cartesian queries?  ... soo many questions... so little information.

Answer (score 0):

By default, MySQL use up to 128 MB for InnoDB buffers.

If you have more memory, edit `my.cnf` and set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to something bigger (eg: `innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M`), then restart MySQL.